# Generate WordCloud from a pandas dataframe with IF condition

Tags: python, pandas, word-cloud

I have a Pandas dataframe:

| Text | Sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| Great | Positive |
| Very bad | Negative |

I am trying to plot a word cloud using this code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud 
from matplotlib import colors
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
color_list=['#4d4d4d','#ffcc00','#000000',]
colormap=colors.ListedColormap(color_list)

words = ' '.join([Text for Text in df['Text']])
wordCloud = WordCloud(background_color='white',colormap=colormap, mode="RGB", width=2000 , height=1000).generate(words)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(wordCloud)
plt.show()
```

How can I adapt the code to show only the negative words as per the classification of column 'Sentiment'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this when creating words:

```
words = ' '.join([Text for Text in df[df['Sentiment']=='Negative']['Text']])
```